# Adding child routes to zend framework module controller

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

Here is my config for my `cortana-resources` route:

```
            'cortana-resources' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/cortana/resources',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Cortana\Controller\Resources',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

The `cortana-resources` route is used throughout the system to reference `http://127.0.0.1/cortana/public/cortana/resources`

I want to add an `add action` in the `resources controller` under the `Cortana` module. How do I accomplish this? It's not resolving correctly.

Comment: What URL do you want, and what error are you currently getting? Your current route config is for `/cortana/resources/<controller>/<action>/` which doesn't sound like it's what you're after.

Comment: I want `/cortana/resources/add` referencing the `ResourcesController` and the `add` action in the `cortana` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, I'd suggest you just change your route config to this:

```
'cortana-resources' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/cortana/resources[/:action]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Cortana\Controller\Resources',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
```

Unless you are wanting to add other controllers below this route, there's no real reason to use child routes here.